# having issues inserting data in Mysql from C++ in Linux

Tags: c++, mysql, linux

Can anyone help me get through just inserting a record with C++ in Linux using the #include<mysql.h> , i have tried almost everything possible , it works just fine making the columns static but cannot pass variables to them at all , even with a cin statement. tried using  cin.get(char &ch): and also cin >> varname, why is this so difficult. ? what am i missing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

// For MySQL Connection
#include <mysql.h>

using namespace std;

int trollyid = 88232;


 // Defining Constant Variables Future Revisions with be with reading a json File
#define SERVER "localhost"
#define USER "root"
#define PASSWORD "xxxxx"
#define DATABASE "txxxx"

int main()
  {
  MYSQL *connect;
connect = mysql_init(NULL);

auto time = std::time(nullptr);

     
   int trollyid = 88232;

     if (!connect)
    {
      cout << "Mysql Initialization Failed";
       // Write XML log for failure
     return 1;
    }

   connect = mysql_real_connect(connect, SERVER, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE, 0,NULL,0);

  if (connect)
  {
     cout << "Connection Succeeded\n";

  }
  else
  {
    cout << "Connection Failed\n";
  }

  MYSQL_RES *res_set;
  MYSQL_ROW row;

  //  MySQL query with your query 

 // -- Need to pass variables into the two field  '665566', 'GOOD')

   mysql_query (connect,"INSERT INTO `Datalog` (`id`, `datecol`, `timecol`, `trolleyid`,   
 `status`) VALUES (NULL, NOW(), NOW(), '665566', 'GOOD')");

 // update: table Datalog with data  VALUES (NULL, NOW(), NOW(), '4444444', 'GOOD')");

 res_set=mysql_store_result(connect);

 //  --------------Just showing tables on testing (Move    

   along)---------------------------------
    // unsigned int numrows = mysql_num_rows(res_set);
   // cout << " Tables in " << DATABASE << " database " << endl;
   // while (((row=mysql_fetch_row(res_set)) !=NULL))
   // {
   // cout << row[i] << endl;
//}

    std::cout
       // ISO 8601: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S, e.g. 2017-07-31 00:42:00+0200.
     << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&time), "%H:%M:%S") << '\n'
    // %m/%d/%y, e.g. 07/31/17
   << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&time), "%D"); 

mysql_close (connect);

return 0; 
 }

// ** EXAMPLE **   
//  TEST INPUT to table: 

 char status[20]; 
 cin  >> nValue;
 cin >> status; 
 cin.getline(status, sizeof(name)); //taking string input

 //  MySQL query with your query 

  mysql_query (connect,"INSERT INTO `Datalog` (`id`, `datecol`,    `timecol`, `trolleyid`, `status`) VALUES (NULL, NOW(), NOW(), 'nValue', 'status')");

so here is the way it works now,  can i put these back into an array ? 

[code][1]
```

Comment: What does "cannot pass variables to them at all" mean? Please show your actual attempt to "pass variables", and clarify how exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: What errors or output do you see? What behaviour do you see when it does not work?

Comment: i have 2 inputs: (Number) 1-1000 and (Status)=GOOD,BAD,WARNING , i want these two numbers to to go into my table under +value1+  and  value2+ . but cannot get anything to let me pass these to inssert into the table.    
   mysql_query (connect,"INSERT INTO `Datalog` (`id`, `datecol`, `timecol`, `trolleyid`,   
 `status`) VALUES (NULL, NOW(), NOW(),'"+Value1+"', '"+value2+"',)

Comment: char status[20]; 
  cin  >> nValue;
  cin >> status; 
  cin.getline(status, sizeof(name)); //taking string input
  
  //  MySQL query with your query 

  mysql_query (connect,"INSERT INTO `Datalog` (`id`, `datecol`, `timecol`, `trolleyid`, `status`) VALUES (NULL, NOW(), NOW(), 'nValue', 'status')");